# Dynamically Regex group manipulation

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

```
node.data =
  node.data.replace(/((?:\d+\.?\d+?)|(?:\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})+)) *([a-zA-Z]+)/,
    function(a,b,c) {
      return value[c] ? a+" (("+(b.replace(',',"") * value[c]).toFixed(2) +
      " "+ names[c]+"))" : a;
    }
  );
```

As you can see my function captures the regex groups, manipulate them if necessary and returns them to be replaced.

What I would like to do is to able manipulate them dynamically so if I have more than one match in a string I would be able to get them from an array or something (like instead of **function(a,b,c)** something like **function(array[])**).

Any Suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `arguments` object. `arguments[0]` is the first argument, `arguments[1]` is the second, and so on.

Comment: So I don't need to pass anything? Just use arguments?

Comment: Nope... arguments -> undefined

Answer (score 1):

Well I did figured it out.. It was the 'g' missing in the expression.. Now it executes the function as many times as it needs.

/((?:\d+.?\d+?)|(?:\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})+)) *([a-zA-Z]+)/**g**